# files.list method of the Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I'm using **searchFiles** function in my Google apps script to search files on Google Drive, which match the given search criteria.

I put code as follows:

```
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder).searchFolders(
      "not title contains '(Orden)'"
    );
```

By the way, it searches not only files whose title doesn't contain '**(Orden)**', but also '**order**'.

*e.g.*

- Compra de **orden**ador
- **Orden**es de medicamentos

How should I modify code in order to search files whose title doesn't contain only '(Orden)' case-sensitive.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive q parameter or [file search](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) is case insensitive.   There is currently no way to make a case sensitive search Orden, ORDEN, orden are all going to be returned.

Comment: Thank you, @DaImTo. At least, would there be any possibility of differentiating (Orden) from Orden? I mean, parenthesis.

Comment: its probably going to be an exact match just ignoring case.

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it helped you.  welcome to stack